# No input file specified. IIS 8 + PHP 7

Tags: php7, iis, microsoft

Recién se está migrando una aplicación de ASP a PHP 7.
En el servidor IIS 8 se tiene UN SOLO website en donde se tienen los diferentes proyectos ejemplo:

```
website(localhost)
|
--/app1
|
 --/app2
```

en la app1 está escrita en PHP 7 y sin problemas funciona; la app2 es la que se esta migrando y esta escrita en C# y funciona sin problema alguno.

El problema aparece cuando creo otra carpeta dentro del website e ingreso la estructura de la aplicación que se está haciendo, esta ultima se esta escribiendo en PHP 7, al entrar en
`localhost/app3` me manda el error **No input file specified**

He revisado muchos tutoriales y ninguno me ha solucionado el problema. He intentado creando otro website pero el servdidor no tiene ip estatica para crear el dns; he revisado el request handler y parece que esta todo bien.

¿Alguien tendrá alguna solución?

Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: @alejandro00 El problema que enfrento es que al entrar a la ruta me devuelve el no input file specified.